# C++: Is there anyway to know what triggered an If-Statement?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an if-statement like this:

```
if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0) {
  cout << "Something is less than zero!"; 
}
```

Is there anyway to know which disjunct in the disjunction triggered the if-statement? Or is it necessary to write three separate if-statements to achieve that end?

EDIT: The goal would be to short-circuit the process. Obviously, writing any more code than three separate if-then statements (for this case) would not work for this goal.

Comment: What kind of way of knowing are you talking about ? Do you mean some variable which will contain index of whether it was x, y, or z or boolean variables like `first`, `second` and `third`. In any case you have to write another if s to test this values.

Comment: If you want to check three different conditions, and do three different actions depending on which condition is true, then it makes sense to have three if statements instead of one.

Comment: Yes, you will have to write three different if statements. Any other convoluted method would be stupid.

Comment: You could store the intermediate results, `if ( (v1=(x<0)) || (v2=(y<0)) || (v3=(z<0)) )`

Comment: Is this for debugging? You use a debugger and view the variable values. If it is for a program, knowing what triggered it would be a decision branch and we write those in c++ as an `if` statement ... so what would you gain there.

Comment: Is the goal for the `cout` to print either "x", "y" or "z" instead of "Something"?

Comment: @davidschwartz but beware reading uninitialised variables due to short circuiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just with that context the answer is no, you cannot really tell which of the three variables is < 0 without adding extra nested ifs for each of the variables. All you know is that at least one of them (but maybe more than one) is.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it would be necessary to write separate if-then statements. But I thought maybe there was a way to short-circuit the process that I was unaware of--thanks for the straight answer!

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of convoluted methods that would be stupid:

```
convoluted_and_stupid( x < 0, y < 0, z < 0 );

void convoluted_and_stupid( bool xlz, bool ylz, bool zyz )
{ 
    if( xlz || ylz || zlz ) 
        cout << "something is less than zero!\n";
    if( xlz )
        cout << "it is x!\n";
    if( ylz )
        cout << "it is y!\n";
    if( zlz )
        cout << "it is z!\n";
}
```